# React: Please pass numbers as strings or BigNumber objects to avoid precision errors

Tags: solidity, web3js, react

Here is my onSubmit function:

```js
onSubmitModifyAllocation = async event => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

  await fund.methods.modifyAllocation(this.state.address, this.state.allocation).send({
    from: accounts[0],
    allocation: web3.utils.toWei(this.state.value, 'ether') // Here is an issue
  });
```

And the form:

```jsx
<form onSubmit={this.onSubmitModifyAllocation}>
  <h4>Modifies the max investment limit allowed for an investor</h4>
  <div>
    <label>Address </label>
    <input
      value={this.state.address}
      onChange={event => this.setState({ address: event.target.value })}
    />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Allocation, denominated in ether </label>
    <input
      value={this.state.allocation}
      onChange={event => this.setState({ allocation: event.target.value })}
    />
  </div>
  <button>Change allocation</button>
</form>
```

I've tried to convert the allocation value to BN, but no luck. What's the best approach to managing the error?

Comment: Strange. `web3.utils.toWei` returns a `string` or a `BN`, see [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#id77) (I'm assuming that you're using web3.js v1.x).

Comment: Oh, you know what? Possibly you need to convert the `BN` to a `string` or a `BigNumber`. Tell you what - add `.toFixed()` at the end of that expression, see if it resolves the problem.

Comment: Make sure `this.state.value` is a string. (Your code doesn't show this being set anywhere, so it's hard to tell you where the issue is.)

Answer (score 1):

Function `web3.utils.toWei` returns a `String` if a string is given as input, and a `BN` otherwise (see [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#id77)).

Since `this.state.value` is not a string, `web3.utils.toWei(this.state.value, 'ether')` returns a `BN`.

But web3.js wants you to pass to function `modifyAllocation` either a `String` or a `BigNumber`, and a `BN` is not a `BigNumber`.

So you can resolve this problem in either one of two ways:

- `web3.utils.toWei(this.state.value.toString(), 'ether')`
- `web3.utils.toWei(this.state.value, 'ether').toFixed()`

Note that I've used `toFixed` in the second option, because `toString` translates large values to scientific format (you know, with the "E" thing), which could technically yield precision-loss.

Comment: The first way throws the error 'Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined' - why is that? 

And the second one doesn't work as well "Unhandled Rejection (Error): Please pass numbers as strings or BigNumber objects to avoid precision errors."

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @VladimirB.: Reading just the first line of your comment, proves that `this.state.value` is `undefined`. Now, I suggest that you first resolve this issue, before we can proceed. By the way, you could (and should) have conducted this basic check before posting the question.

Comment: It works well when I put the value in wei, but throws an error when I'm using `web3.utils.toWei` in any form.

Comment: @VladimirB.: Your description suggest that `this.state.value === undefined`, and I suggest that you fix this problem to begin with. Even if it is somehow accepted by some function, it doesn't mean that this function operates as you hope it will.

Answer (score 0):

use This Library https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/ as like

```
import BigNumber from "bignumber.js";
// or
import { BigNumber } from "bignumber.js";
let x = new BigNumber(123.4567);
let y = BigNumber('123456.7e-3');
let z = new BigNumber(x);
x.isEqualTo(y) && y.isEqualTo(z) && x.isEqualTo(z);
```